# Do compiler default options refer to implicit defaults, or default explicit Visual Studio project settings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, compilation

In the [Visual Studio compiler options documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), various options are described (in a somewhat inconsistent way) as "on by default", "off by default", or similar.

As an example, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84wcsx8x.aspx) states that `/Zc:forScope` is on by default.

The product being described in this set of documentation is "Visual Studio 2013" (as opposed to specifically the C++ compiler). My question therefore is, does this refer to the fact that a newly created project will pass the `/Zc:forScope` option to the compiler explicitly on the command line (which I have verified it does), or does it mean that the option is implicit if you call `cl.exe` without specifying it?

In a more general sense, if the documentation for a specific compiler option mentions a default behaviour, then can I safely ignore the switch on the command line if the default behaviour is what I want?

My assumption has always been that defaults are implicit, but then I noticed that newly created Visual Studio projects explicitly pass some of them (e.g. the aforementioned `/Zc:forScope`, or `/analyze-`). If my assumption is correct, then why the redundancy?

EDIT: I have found contradictory information in the documentation. If you run `cl.exe /?` then some of the options are described as "default" (suggesting that the defaults are implicit), but then [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173502%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes a default *"when an application is compiled in the development environment"*, which suggests to me that it is an IDE default.

Comment: There's [this](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/cl/cl/initial.htm), chances are you have seen it while searching around, sadly it's quite old (cl version 13.00 corresponds to VS 2003, if I'm not mistaken).